# Word for "unseen characters" in Theater

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "unseen characters" in theatre?

Also on-stage characters other than cast or company?

Comment: Hello Lys. Welcome to EL&U. Would you please provide an example sentence where you want this word to be used?

Comment: @TusharRaj The question is clear and complete enough.

Comment: @Kris: Are we to define unseen characters or on-stage characters? One word covering both? Separate words for each?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you expand your answer to give a definition and/or examples of what you mean by "unseen characters"? In what plays have you seen them?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response and I apologize for any confusion. I would like an answer to both questions if possible (one word for on-stage character and another also one word for unseen character). As for the unseen characters I was initially referring to characters that are only mentioned by name and do not make any real appearance in the show. Examples include: Rosaline- Romeo & Juliet and Godot-waiting for Godot.

Comment: If you have two questions, you should post two separate questions. That makes the site more useful to other people looking for answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [**Kuroko**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroko) (黒子 "black person"/"black clothes"), who were stagehands in traditional Japanese [Kabuki Theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabuki) :

> They move scenery and props on stage, aiding in scene changes and costume changes. They will also often play the role of animals, will-o-the-wisps, or other roles which are played not by an actor in full costume, but by holding a prop. Kuroko wear all black<sup>**1**</sup>, head to toe, in order to imply that they are invisible and not part of the action onstage.

It has been suggested that this practice led to the stereotypical image of Ninjas being dressed all in black: as the above Wiki-page continues:

> As this convention was extended to kabuki actors depicting stealthy ninja, historian Stephen Turnbull suggested that the stereotypical image of a ninja dressed all in black derived from kabuki. The theatrical convention of dressing ninja characters as apparent stagehands to imply stealth and to surprise audiences contributed to this popular image, in contrast to the historical reality that real ninjas usually dressed like civilians.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> In a scene set in a snowstorm, they will wear all white and are referred to as **Yukigo** (雪子 snow person); in a scene at sea, they will wear all blue and are referred to as **Namigo** (波子 wave person).

Answer (score 0):

There can be "off stage" characters, such as the giant's wife in "Into the Woods". In fact, I think I’ve only seen this used where a character is too fantastical to be within budget. This is sometimes an opportunity for local theatre groups to get some celebrity to record the lines in advance. I think they’re just generally considered "speaking roles", although you never see the actor (and they might not be in the building).

Other people involved in a stage production include the band or orchestra. Usually, they’re paid outsiders and might not be considered cast nor crew. Sometimes, scenes require members of the band on stage.

Answer (score -3):

Collectively they may be called ***stage crew*** and individually, ***stagehand***.

I am more familiar with *crew* being used generally for all purposes in the film and theater fields and *stagehand* may even be a bit impolite these days.

***[Stagehand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagehand)*** (WP)

> A stagehand is a person who works backstage or behind the scenes in theatres, film, television, or location performance. Their work include setting up the scenery, lights, sound, props, rigging, and special effects for a production.
>   …
>   Stagehands are usually skilled in multiple disciplines, including rigging, carpentry, stage electrics, stage lighting, audio, video/projection, and props. Stagehands are often responsible for operating the systems during shows or taping and also for the repair and maintenance of the equipment. Most stagehands have a general knowledge of all the phases of a production, but tend to develop specialties and focus on specific areas.

*See also,*
[Types of stagehand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagehand#Types_of_stagehand)

***[Crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew)***

> A crew is a body or a class of people who work at a common activity, generally in a structured or hierarchical organization.
>   …

*Cf.* **Cast & Crew** Anyone working in theater who is not part of the cast then would probably be a member of the "crew".

Comment: But the stagehands and other crew aren't "characters" usually...

Comment: @miltonaut From the context, it appears that the OP meant "persons" (working behind the scenes), not characters (as in characters the play).

Comment: Well, in TV and Film, there are "extras" who may not be listed in the cast but aren't part of the crew. I've just never seen anyone who appeared onstage who wasn't listed in a theatre program, even if they're just listed under "Chorus" or "Dancers" or "Villagers".

Comment: @miltonaut Extras are part of the cast.

Comment: Yes, I know. But they could be considered "unseen characters" since they are more like living set pieces than regular/actual named characters and are often not listed in the credits. That's one of the reasons we need more clarification from the OP.